# Joining Three DbSets into one new DbSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get 3 DbSets and take out some of the values in them and return a new DbSet. I'm able to get a populate a single room, but I'm having trouble getting a group of rooms.

Here is getting a single room, which works fine.

Here is my Repository call.

```
    public Room GetRoom(Guid id)
    {
        var room = _db1Context.ClientRoom.FirstOrDefault(x =>x.Id == id);
        var roomDetails = _db2Context.RoomDetail.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientRoomId== id);
        var summary = _db3Context.RoomSummary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientRoomId == id);

        var room = _roomFactory.BuildRoomEntity(room, roomDetails, summary);
        return room;
    }
```

Here is my Factory Call

```
public Room BuildRoomEntity(ClientRoom room, RoomDetail roomDetail, RoomSummary summary)
    {
        var room = new Room()
        {
            Id = room.ClientRoomId,                                                      
            Name = room.DisplayName,                          
            Description = roomDetail.Description,
            Status = summary.Status,
            OnlineStatus = summary.OnlineStatus,
            ServicePlan = roomdetail.ServicePlan
            Incidents = room.Incident == null ? new List<Incident>() : room.Incident.ToList(),
            Devices = roomDetail.Devices == null ? new List<Device>() : roomDetail.Devices.ToList()
        };

        return room;
    }
```

I would like to do something similar except get a List of rooms
Here is what my Repo call would look like.

```
    public List<Room> GetRooms()
    {
        var room = _db1Context.room;
        var roomDetails = _db2Context.RoomDetails;
        var roomSummary = _db3Context.RoomSummaries;

        var room = _roomFactory.BuildRoomEntity(room, roomDetails, summary);
        return room;
    }
```

This is where I'm stuck, I'd like to use Linq to create a list of Rooms based on the values passed in from the other dbsets

```
public List<Room> BuildRoomEntity(DbSet<ClientRoom> room, DbSet<RoomDetail> roomDetail, DbSet<RoomSummary> summary)
    {

        var rooms = new List<Room>()
        {

        }

        return rooms;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're classes are configured like this:

```
public class ClientRoom
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public RoomDetail RoomDetail { get; set; }
    public RoomSummary RoomSummary { get; set; }
}
```

Then, You can and should use `DbSet.Include`.

```
var room = _db1Context.room
room.Include(r=>r.RoomDetail);
room.Include(r=>r.RoomSummary);
```

If you only have the Ids in the sub-tables then you can use a join:

```
var room = _db1Context.room;
var roomDetails = _db2Context.RoomDetails;
var roomSummary = _db3Context.RoomSummaries;

var subtables = roomDetails.Join(roomSummary, rd=>ClientRoomId, rs=>rs.ClientRoomId, (roomDetails, summary)=>new {roomDetails.ClientRoomId, roomDetails, roomSummary});

var rooms = room.Join(subtables, r=>r.Id, sub=>sub.ClientRoomId, (room, sub)=>
    new Room()
        {
            Id = room.Id,                                                      
            Name = room.DisplayName,                          
            Description = sub.roomDetail.Description,
            Status = sub.summary.Status,
            OnlineStatus = sub.summary.OnlineStatus,
            ServicePlan = sub.roomdetail.ServicePlan
            Incidents = room.Incident == null ? new List<Incident>() : room.Incident.ToList(),
            Devices = sub.roomDetail.Devices == null ? new List<Device>() : roomDetail.Devices.ToList()
        });
```